# How To Invoke Multiple services in a single itinerary?

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010, toolkit

I have designed an itinerary as below:
[image]

1. Receive a request
2. Transform the request
3. Send the transformed message to service1 and get a response

It works Perfectly, but I want to invoke another service for the same request.

Where should I do the second transformation and service invocation?

Comment: I think you would probably just create another itinerary that also subscribes to the same message.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in single ininerary?